problem with importing modules provided by the kivymd documentation
This is the second time in my application that I have tried to reproduce code from the kivymd documentation without success, it does not find the specific module, I have already installed the latest version of kivymd which is the master.
this is the code I'm trying to use:
myapp.py:

import kivy

kivy.require('2.1.0') # replace with your current kivy version !


from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivymd.uix.pickers import MDDockedDatePicker

from kivymd.app import MDApp

from windowmanager import *
from home import *
from controledeestoque import *
from pedidos import *
from criarpedido import *


class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file("KV.kv")
        return self.root

    def show_date_picker(self, focus):
        if not focus:
            return

        date_dialog = MDDockedDatePicker()
        # You have to control the position of the date picker dialog yourself.
        date_dialog.pos = [
            self.root.ids.field.center_x - date_dialog.width / 2,
            self.root.ids.field.y - (date_dialog.height + dp(32)),
        ]
        date_dialog.open()

main.py:
from myapp import *

Window.maximize()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()

KV.kv:
WindowManager:
    Home:
    id: home

    ControleDeEstoque:
    id: controledeestoque

    Pedidos:
    id: pedidos

    CriarPedido:
    id: criarpedido


<Home>:
    name: "home"

    MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint: (1, 1)

    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color: (0, 255, 0)
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint: (1, 1)


        MDFloatLayout:
            md_bg_color: (0, 255, 255)
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: (0.5, 0.05)
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

            MDRaisedButton:
                #size_hint_x: .9
                text: "CONTROLE DE ESTOQUE"
                bg: True
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .1, "center_y": .5}
                on_release: app.root.current = "controledeestoque"

            MDRaisedButton:
                #size_hint_x: .9
                text: "CONTROLE DE VENDAS"
                bg: True
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                on_press: ""

            MDRaisedButton:
                #size_hint_x: .9
                text: "CONTROLE OPERACIONAL"
                bg: True
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .5}
                on_press: ""


<ControleDeEstoque>:
    name: "controledeestoque"

    MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint: (1, 1)

    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color: (0, 255, 0)
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint: (1, 1)


        MDFloatLayout:
            md_bg_color: (0, 255, 255)
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint: (0.5, 0.05)
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

            MDRaisedButton:
                #size_hint_x: .9
                text: "PEDIDOS"
                bg: True
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .1, "center_y": .5}
                on_release: app.root.current = "pedidos"

            MDRaisedButton:
                #size_hint_x: .9
                text: "ESTOQUE"
                bg: True
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                on_press: ""

            MDRaisedButton:
                #size_hint_x: .9
                text: "PRODUTOS"
                bg: True
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .5}
                on_press: ""

        MDRaisedButton:
            #size_hint_x: .9
            text: "VOLTAR"
            bg: True
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .9}
            on_release: app.root.current = "home"

<Pedidos>:
    name: "pedidos"
    MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint: (1, 1)

    MDFloatLayout:
        id: id_pedidos_window
        md_bg_color: (0, 255, 0)
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint: (1, 1)

        AnchorLayout:
            md_bg_color: (255, 0, 255)
            id: anchor_id
            size_hint: (1.2, 1.3)
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .43, "center_y": .43}


        MDFloatLayout:
            md_bg_color: (0, 255, 255)
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint: (0.05, 0.9)
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .5}

            MDRaisedButton:
                #size_hint_x: .9
                text: "CRIAR PEDIDO"
                bg: True
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .9}
                on_release: app.root.current = "criarpedido"

            MDRaisedButton:
                #size_hint_x: .9
                text: "MODIFICAR PEDIDO"
                bg: True
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .8}
                on_press: ""

            MDRaisedButton:
                #size_hint_x: .9
                text: "VER PEDIDOS"
                bg: True
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .7}
                on_press: ""

        MDRaisedButton:
            #size_hint_x: .9
            text: "VOLTAR"
            bg: True
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .1}
            on_release: app.root.current = "controledeestoque"

<CriarPedido>:
    name: "criarpedido"

    MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint: (1, 1)

    MDFloatLayout:
        md_bg_color: (0, 255, 0)
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint: (1, 1)

        MDFloatLayout:
            md_bg_color: (0, 255, 255)
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint: (0.5, 0.9)
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}

            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "QUANTIDADE"
                mode: "rectangle"
                size_hint: (0.1, 0.05)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .1, "center_y": .5}

            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "VALOR"
                mode: "rectangle"
                size_hint: (0.1, 0.05)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .3, "center_y": .5}

            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "TAXAS"
                mode: "rectangle"
                size_hint: (0.1, 0.05)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .6, "center_y": .5}

            MDTextField:
                id: field
                mode: "outlined"
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .85}
                size_hint_x: .5
                on_focus: app.show_date_picker(self.focus)

                MDTextFieldHintText:
                    text: "Docked date picker"

                MDTextFieldHelperText:
                    text: "MM/DD/YYYY"
                    mode: "persistent"

                MDTextFieldTrailingIcon:
                    icon: "calendar"


            #ESCOLHER PRODUTO
            MDFloatLayout:
                md_bg_color: (0, 0, 255)
                size_hint: (1, 0.05)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.9}

                MDBoxLayout:
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                    Spinner:
                        id: id_selecionar_produto
                        text: 'PRODUTO'
                        values: ""
                        #size_hint: (1, .07)
                        on_text: root.spinner_select(search_mode_type.text)

                    MDIconButton:
                        icon: "plus"
                        style: "standard"


            # SEGUNDA LINHA 3 SPINNERS
            MDFloatLayout:
                md_bg_color: (255, 0, 255)
                orientation: "vertical"
                size_hint: (1, 0.05)
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .8}


                #DESTINATÁRIO
                MDFloatLayout:
                    md_bg_color: (0, 0, 255)
                    size_hint: (0.3, 1)
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .1, "center_y": 0.5}

                    MDBoxLayout:
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                        Spinner:
                            id: id_selecionar_produto
                            text: 'DESTINATÁRIO'
                            values: ""
                            #size_hint: (1, .07)
                            on_text: root.spinner_select(search_mode_type.text)

                        MDIconButton:
                            icon: "plus"
                            style: "standard"


                #DECLARAÇÃO
                MDFloatLayout:
                    md_bg_color: (0, 0, 255)
                    size_hint: (0.3, 1)
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": 0.5}

                    MDBoxLayout:
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                        Spinner:
                            id: id_selecionar_produto
                            text: 'DECLARAÇÃO'
                            values: ""
                            #size_hint: (1, .07)
                            on_text: root.spinner_select(search_mode_type.text)

                        MDIconButton:
                            icon: "plus"
                            style: "standard"

                #ENDEREÇO
                MDFloatLayout:
                    md_bg_color: (0, 0, 255)
                    size_hint: (0.3, 1)
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": 0.5}

                    MDBoxLayout:
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                        Spinner:
                            id: id_selecionar_produto
                            text: 'ENDEREÇO'
                            values: ""
                            #size_hint: (1, .07)
                            on_text: root.spinner_select(search_mode_type.text)

                        MDIconButton:
                            icon: "plus"
                            style: "standard"

    MDRaisedButton:
        #size_hint_x: .9
        text: "VOLTAR"
        bg: True
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .1}
        on_release: app.root.current = "controledeestoque"

There are other classes that are not here, but at first I think you can understand, it was supposed to be a common import, but it gives an error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/thiagodesk/PycharmProjects/pasta2/GlobalShop/venv/main.py", line 1, in 
from myapp import *
File "/home/thiagodesk/PycharmProjects/pasta2/GlobalShop/venv/myapp.py", line 12, in 
from kivymd.uix.pickers import MDDockedDatePicker
ImportError: cannot import name 'MDDockedDatePicker' from 'kivymd.uix.pickers' (/home/thiagodesk/PycharmProjects/pasta2/GlobalShop/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kivymd/uix/pickers/init.py)

Look at the file: /home/thiagodesk/PycharmProjects/pasta2/GlobalShop/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kivymd/uix/pickers/init.py and see if it imports MDDockedDatePicker.
